# How to create a gradient which fades an image to a background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I would like to achieve in Photoshop this type of effect, to create a gradient which fades an image to a background. I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say!

[image]

Look forward to hear from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following.

1. Open your background image in Photoshop.
2. Add a new layer and fill it with the color you want your gradient to be. In the image in the question it's like a very dark blue-grey color.

[image: Gradient layer]

3. On the gradient color layer, add a layer mask([image: Layer mask]).
4. Choose the gradient tool and make sure that the gradient is black to white and on the layer mask, draw a gradient from above the image to about the center(you may have to do this several times before getting the correct result. Just undo and retry).

You can then add the other images and text at the bottom of the image and change the color of the gradient if you want to.

[image: Making gradient]

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: Result]